# Sending email in SharePoint 2013 Workflow with the Email Utility

Tags: workflow, 2013, workflow-activity

I have been searching for documentation on the SP - Utilities components in visual studio 2012 with no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I am simply trying to figure out how to get the Email component working in the activity designer so I can send emails in the workflow.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to configure Outgoing Email settings and SMTP Server to send mail using SP Utilities

Answer (score 1):

The below method worked in Sharepoint 2010 using Visual studio 2010.

A. Use Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities Namespace

**Do the following in your Email Activity,**

B. Create an object for SendEmail class,

Ex : `SendEmail sE = new SendEmail();`

C. Assign from address, To address, Subject, etc, like below

Ex:    `sE.From = "abc@email.com";`
    `sE.To = "xyz@email.com";`
`sE.CC = "xyz@email.com";`
    `sE.Subject = "Test mail";`
`sE.Body = "Mail Body";`

D. Declare a string Body and assign the sE.Body to it,

Ex: 
   `string body = sE.Body;`

E. Then create a String Dictionary and put SendMail object into it.
Ex: 
    `StringDictionary headers = new StringDictionary();`
   `headers.Add("to", sE.To);`
   `headers.Add("cc", sE.CC);`
        `headers.Add("bcc", sE.BCC);`
      `headers.Add("from", sE.From);`
       `headers.Add("subject", sE.Subject);`
       `headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");`

F. Now you can send the mail, using `SPUtility.SendEmail(web, headers, body);`

Ex:    `SPUtility.SendEmail(web, headers, body); // web --> SpWeb object.`

**Overload methods of SendEmail are as follows,**

a. `SendEmail(SPWeb, StringDictionary, String)` -   Sends an e-mail message.

b. `SendEmail(SPWeb, StringDictionary, String, Boolean)` -  Sends the e-mail message to the specified address.

c. `SendEmail(SPWeb, Boolean, Boolean, String, String, String)` -   Sends an e-mail message.

d. `SendEmail(SPWeb, Boolean, Boolean, String, String, String, Boolean)` -  Sends the e-mail message to the specified address.

Reference,

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail(v=office.14).aspx

**Note,**

1. Configure SMTP, Incoming and Outgoing emails in SharePoint Server 2010.

Comment: The question is asking for a solution using the Activity Designer, not code.